# How to customize formik handleChange

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

Hi I am trying to build a handleChange method that will not only change the value of a dropdown but also dispatch a redux action which we need. Unfortunately the form is built with formik so formik.handleChange is being used. Below Im attaching two code snippets -- a parent component from which the formik value is coming and a child component where its being used.

1. Parent Component

```
/* eslint-disable no-nested-ternary */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Grid, Typography, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import DoNotDisturbIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DoNotDisturb';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { NavigateRoutes } from '../../../constant';
import SwapCourseLocation from '../../admin-user/swap-course-location';
import { DialogAtom } from '../../../components/atoms';
import { getFormattedDate } from '../../../utils/methods';
import styles from './style';
import useStyles from '../../../custom-hooks/useStyles';
import Loader from '../../../components/atoms/loader';
import DataGridProTable from '../../../components/atoms/data-grid-pro';
import { Student, SwapCourse } from './helper';
import StudentHeader from './header';
import { SwapCourseDialogFooter } from '../../admin-user/students/helper';
import { SwapIcon, MailIcon } from '../../../assets/svg';
// import { getAllCourseService } from '../../../store/services/auth';
import Constant from '../../../store/constant';
import useLocationCoordinator from '../../../custom-hooks/useLocationCoordinator';
import { setLocalStorage } from '../../../utils/localStorageMethod';
import CommonProfileImage from '../../../components/molecules/common/CommonProfileImage';
import useStudent from '../../../custom-hooks/useStudent';
// import useStudent from '../../../custom-hooks/useStudent';

export default function StudentList({
  setDialogOpen,
  setLoading,
  refreshList,
  loading,
  visibleFields,
  fileHeaders,
  // marksOpen,
  setCourseData,
  courseData,
  setOpenDialog,
}) {
  const classes = useStyles(styles)();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = React.useState([]);
  const validationSchema = Yup.object({});
  const coordinatorInfo = useLocationCoordinator();
  const students = coordinatorInfo?.students;
  const assignedLocations = coordinatorInfo?.assignedLocations;
  const assignedYears = coordinatorInfo?.assignedYears;
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
  const [studentData, setStudentData] = useState([]);
  const [gridLoading, setGridLoading] = useState(true);
  const [locations, setLocationData] = useState([]);
  const [years, setYearsData] = useState([]);
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [customForm, setCustomForm] = useState('');
  const [isSwapCourseDialog, setSwapCourseOrLocation] = useState(false);
  const locationCoordinatorData = useSelector((state) => state?.getLocationCoordinator);
  const selectedYearRedux = locationCoordinatorData?.selectedYear;
  const selectedLocationRedux = locationCoordinatorData?.selectedLocations;
  const [swapCourseLocationInfo, setCourseLocationInfo] = useState({
    studentId: '',
    studentName: '',
    acedemicYear: '',
    courseFrom: '',
    courseTo: '',
    locationFrom: '',
    locationTo: '',
    sectionFrom: '',
    sectionTo: '',
    changeLogs: '',
  });
  const [disableMovestudent, setDisableMovestudent] = useState(true);
  const studentInfo = useStudent();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log(selectedLocationRedux?.value);
  // }, [selectedLocationRedux]);
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      academicYear: years[0]?.id,
      locationId: locations[0]?.id,
      courseId: courseData[0]?.id,
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: () => {
      setLoading(true);
    },

  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage('locationDashboard', false);
    setStudentData(students);
  }, [students]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setStudentData([]);
      setRowData([]);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocationData(assignedLocations);
    setYearsData(assignedYears);
    if (selectedLocationRedux?.value) {
      formik.setFieldValue('locationId', selectedLocationRedux?.value);
    } else {
      formik.setFieldValue('locationId', assignedLocations[0]?.id);
    }

    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const selectedYear = assignedYears.filter((opt) => opt?.id.substring(0, 4) === currentYear.toString());
    if (selectedYearRedux?.id) {
      formik.setFieldValue('academicYear', selectedYearRedux?.id);
    } else {
      formik.setFieldValue('academicYear', selectedYear[0]?.id);
    }
    // formik.setFieldValue('academicYear', selectedYear[0]?.id);
  }, [assignedLocations, assignedYears]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCourseData(studentInfo?.courses);
  }, [studentInfo?.courses]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setError('');
    setGridLoading(true);
    setSelectedRows([]);
    const locData = assignedLocations?.filter(
      (i) => i?.id === formik.values.locationId,
    );
    const date = getFormattedDate(new Date());
    const file = `${locData[0]?.name}-${formik.values.academicYear}-${date}`;
    setFileName(file);
    const payload = {
      locationId: formik?.values?.locationId,
      academicYear: formik?.values?.academicYear,
      courseId: formik?.values?.courseId,
    };
    if (payload?.locationId && payload?.academicYear && payload?.courseId && formik?.values?.courseId?.[0] !== undefined) {
      refreshList(payload);
    }
  }, [
    formik?.values?.locationId,
    formik?.values?.academicYear,
    formik?.values?.courseId,
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = new Student(studentData);
    setRowData(data);
    setGridLoading(loading);
  }, [studentData]);

  const getMarksHeader = () => (
    <div>
      <span style={{ height: '5vh' }}>
        {t('MARKS')}
      </span>
      <div>{t('Q2')}</div>
    </div>
  );
  // const getBonusHeader = () => (
  //   <div>
  //     <span>
  //       {t('BONUS_MARKS')}
  //     </span>
  //     {/* <div>{t('Marks')}</div> */}
  //   </div>
  // );
  const getNewReturningHeader = () => (
    <div>
      <span style={{ height: '5vh' }}>
        {t('New / ')}
      </span>
      <div>{t('Returning')}</div>
    </div>
  );
  const getHomeworkHeader = () => (
    <div>
      <span style={{ height: '5vh', left: -14 }}>
        {t('HOMEWORK')}
      </span>
      <div>{t('Q2')}</div>
    </div>
  );
  const viewLogs = (onClose) => {
    onClose(false);
    navigate(NavigateRoutes.STUDENTS_LOGS);
  };

  const handleMoveStudent = () => {
    customForm.handleSubmit();
  };

  const refreshStudentData = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const payload = {
      locationId: formik?.values?.locationId,
      academicYear: formik?.values?.academicYear,
      courseId: formik?.values?.courseId,
    };
    // setTimeout(() => {
    refreshList(payload);
    // }, 1000);
  };

  const swapCourseDialogFooter = (
    <SwapCourseDialogFooter
      classes={classes}
      t={t}
      primaryHandle={handleMoveStudent}
      secHandle={() => setSwapCourseOrLocation(false)}
      viewLogs={viewLogs}
      disableMovestudent={disableMovestudent}
    />
  );
  const isChangeLogVisible = false;
  const swapCourseLocation = (
    <SwapCourseLocation
      refreshStudentsData={refreshStudentData}
      {...{
        setCourseLocationInfo,
        swapCourseLocationInfo,
        setCustomForm,
        setSwapCourseOrLocation,
        courseData,
        isChangeLogVisible,
        setDisableMovestudent,

      }}
    />
  );

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const columnsData = [
      {
        field: 'profilePhoto',
        headerName: t('PICTURES'),
        sortable: false,
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('PICTURES')),
        renderCell: (rowInfo) => (
          <CommonProfileImage
            key={rowInfo?.id}
            src={rowInfo?.row?.studentInfo?.profilePhoto}
          />
        ),
        headerClassName: 'pictureHeader',
        cellClassName: 'pictureCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'studentName',
        headerName: t('STUDENT_NAME'),
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('STUDENT_NAME')),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'studentNameHeader',
        cellClassName: 'studentNameCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'parentName',
        headerName: t('PARENT_NAME'),
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('PARENT_NAME')),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'commonHeader',
        cellClassName: 'commonCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'phoneNumber',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('CONTACT_NO')),
        headerName: t('CONTACT_NO'),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'phoneNumberHeader',
        cellClassName: 'phoneNumberCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'course',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('COURSE')),
        headerName: t('COURSE'),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'courseHeader',
        cellClassName: 'courseCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'section',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('SECTION')),
        headerName: t('SECTION'),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'courseHeader',
        cellClassName: 'courseCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'newReturning',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('NEW_RETURNING')),
        headerName: getNewReturningHeader(),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'newReturningHeader',
        cellClassName: 'newReturningCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'marksQ1',
        disableColumnResize: 'false',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('MARKS')),
        sortable: false,
        headerName: t('Q1'),
        align: 'center',
        headerClassName: 'marksHeader',
        cellClassName: 'marksCell',
        renderCell: (cellValues) => (
          <span
            className={cellValues?.row?.marksQ1 >= cellValues?.row?.Q1PassingCriteria ? classes.marksGreen
              : cellValues?.row?.marksQ1 < (parseInt(cellValues?.row?.Q1PassingCriteria, 10) - 10) ? classes.marksRed
                : cellValues?.row?.marksQ1 >= (parseInt(cellValues?.row?.Q1PassingCriteria, 10) - 10) ? classes.marksYellow : classes.marksGrey}
            onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'marks', 'Q1')}
          >
            {cellValues?.row?.Q1PassingCriteria ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.marksQ1) ? cellValues?.row?.marksQ1 : Number(cellValues?.row?.marksQ1).toFixed(2) : '-'}
            {cellValues?.row?.Q1PassingCriteria && !cellValues?.row?.Q1Attended ? '(A)' : ''}
          </span>

        ),
      },
      {
        field: 'marksQ2',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('MARKS')),
        headerName: getMarksHeader(),
        disableColumnResize: 'false',
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'marksHeaderSpan',
        cellClassName: 'marksQ3Cell',
        sortable: false,
        renderCell: (cellValues) => (
          <span
            className={cellValues?.row?.marksQ2 >= cellValues?.row?.Q2PassingCriteria ? classes.marksGreen
              : cellValues?.row?.marksQ2 < (parseInt(cellValues?.row?.Q2PassingCriteria, 10) - 10)
                ? classes.marksRed : cellValues?.row?.marksQ2 >= (parseInt(cellValues?.row?.Q2PassingCriteria, 10) - 10) ? classes.marksYellow : classes.marksGrey}
            onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'marks', 'Q2')}
          >
            {cellValues?.row?.Q2PassingCriteria
              ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.marksQ2) ? cellValues?.row?.marksQ2 : Number(cellValues?.row?.marksQ2).toFixed(2) : '-'}
            {cellValues?.row?.Q2PassingCriteria && !cellValues?.row?.Q2Attended ? '(A)' : ''}
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        field: 'marksQ3',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('MARKS')),
        headerName: t('Q3'),
        headerClassName: 'marksQ3Header',
        cellClassName: 'marksQ3Cell',
        sortable: false,
        renderCell: (cellValues) => (
          <span
            className={cellValues?.row?.marksQ3 >= cellValues?.row?.Q3PassingCriteria ? classes.marksGreen
              : cellValues?.row?.marksQ3 < (parseInt(cellValues?.row?.Q3PassingCriteria, 10) - 10)
                ? classes.marksRed : cellValues?.row?.marksQ3 >= (parseInt(cellValues?.row?.Q3PassingCriteria, 10) - 10) ? classes.marksYellow : classes.marksGrey}
            onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'marks', 'Q3')}
          >
            {cellValues?.row?.Q3PassingCriteria
              ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.marksQ3) ? cellValues?.row?.marksQ3 : Number(cellValues?.row?.marksQ3).toFixed(2) : '-'}
            {cellValues?.row?.Q3PassingCriteria && !cellValues?.row?.Q3Attended ? '(A)' : ''}
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        field: 'homeworkQ1',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('HOMEWORK')),
        headerName: t('Q1'),
        align: 'center',
        headerClassName: 'marksHeader',
        cellClassName: 'marksCell',
        sortable: false,
        renderCell: (cellValues) => (
          <span
            className={cellValues?.row?.Q1HomeWorkWeightage
              ? classes.homeworkColor : classes.marksGrey}
            onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'homework-marks', 'Q1')}
          >
            {cellValues?.row?.Q1HomeWorkWeightage
              ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ1) ? cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ1 : Number(cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ1).toFixed(2) : '-'}
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        field: 'homeworkQ2',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('HOMEWORK')),
        headerName: getHomeworkHeader(),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'homeworkHeaderSpan',
        cellClassName: 'marksQ3Cell',
        sortable: false,
        renderCell: (cellValues) => (
          <span
            className={cellValues?.row?.Q2HomeWorkWeightage
              ? classes.homeworkColor : classes.marksGrey}
            onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'homework-marks', 'Q2')}
          >
            {cellValues?.row?.Q2HomeWorkWeightage
              ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ2) ? cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ2 : Number(cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ2).toFixed(2) : '-'}
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        field: 'homeworkQ3',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('HOMEWORK')),
        sortable: false,
        headerName: t('Q3'),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'marksQ3Header',
        cellClassName: 'marksQ3Cell',
        renderCell: (cellValues) => (
          <span
            className={cellValues?.row?.Q3HomeWorkWeightage
              ? classes.homeworkColor : classes.marksGrey}
            onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'homework-marks', 'Q3')}
          >
            {cellValues?.row?.Q3HomeWorkWeightage
              ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ3) ? cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ3 : Number(cellValues?.row?.homeworkQ3).toFixed(2) : '-'}
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        field: 'bonus',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('BONUS_MARKS')),
        sortable: false,
        headerName: t('BONUS_MARKS'),
        headerClassName: 'bonusHeaderSpan',
        cellClassName: 'bonusCell',
        renderCell: (cellValues) => (
          <span
            className={classes.marksGreen}
            onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'bonus', null)}
          >
            {cellValues?.row?.bonus || 0}
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        field: 'grade',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('GRADE')),
        sortable: false,
        headerName: t('GRADE'),
        // align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'gradeHeader',
        cellClassName: 'gradeCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'gpa',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('GPA')),
        sortable: false,
        headerName: t('GPA'),
        // align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'gradeHeader',
        cellClassName: 'gradeCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'annualScore',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('ANNUAL_SCORE')),
        headerName: t('ANNUAL_SCORE'),
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'commonHeader',
        cellClassName: 'commonCell',
      },
      {
        field: 'actions',
        hide: !visibleFields?.includes(t('ACTIONS')),
        headerName: t('ACTIONS'),
        sortable: false,
        headerAlign: 'left',
        align: 'left',
        headerClassName: 'commonHeader',
        cellClassName: 'actionCells',
        renderCell: (row) => (
          <span style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <span
              style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}
            >
              <IconButton onClick={() => {
                const data = new SwapCourse(row);
                setCourseLocationInfo(data);
                setSwapCourseOrLocation(true);
              }}
              >
                <SwapIcon />

              </IconButton>
            </span>
            <span>
              <IconButton
                onClick={() => {
                  const { manabadiEmail } = row.row.studentInfo;
                  const emailParents = [];
                  emailParents.push(row?.row?.parent1Info?.personalEmail?.toString());
                  emailParents.push(row?.row?.parent2Info?.personalEmail?.toString());
                  dispatch({ type: Constant.SET_MAIL_SUBJECT, payload: '' });
                  dispatch({ type: Constant.SET_MAIL_BODY, payload: '' });
                  dispatch({ type: Constant.RECIPIENTS, payload: [manabadiEmail] });
                  dispatch({ type: Constant.MAIL_FILTER, payload: 'Student' });
                  dispatch({ type: Constant.MAIL_PARENTS, payload: emailParents });
                  setLocalStorage('selectedLocation', row.row.enrolled_courses[0].location.id);
                  setLocalStorage('selectedYear', row.row.enrolled_courses[0].academicYear);
                  setLocalStorage('showLocationFilterRecipients', false);
                  setLocalStorage('showLocationAnnouncementsRecipients', false);
                  setLocalStorage('showSelectAllinEmail', false);
                  navigate(NavigateRoutes.LOCATION_COORDINATOR_EMAIL);
                }}
              >
                <MailIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </span>
          </span>
        ),
      },
    ];
    setColumns(columnsData);
  }, [visibleFields]);
  const showDetail = () => {
    if (gridLoading || loading) {
      return (
        <Grid>
          <Loader message={t('LOADING')} />
        </Grid>
      );
    }
    if (studentData?.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Grid xs={12} md={12} mt={5} className={classes.studentsList}>
          <DataGridProTable
            data={rowData}
            columns={columns}
            autoHeight
            hideFooter
            disableColumnFilter
            disableColumnSelector
            checkboxSelection
            disableColumnMenu
            disableColumnResize
            disableSelectionOnClick
            ColumnUnsorted
            ColumnSortedAscending
            ColumnSortedDescending
            onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
              setError('');
              const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
              const selectedData = rowData.filter((row) => selectedIDs.has(row.id));
              setSelectedRows(selectedData);
            }}
            loading={gridLoading}
          />
        </Grid>
      );
    }
    if (studentData?.length === 0) {
      return (
        <Grid container style={{ textAlign: 'center', height: '5vw', marginTop: '7vw' }} className={classes.noData}>
          <Grid item xs={12} justifyContent="center">
            <DoNotDisturbIcon />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} justifyContent="center">
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="text.secondary">
              {t('NO_DATA')}
            </Typography>

          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }

    return null;
  };
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid xs={12}>
        <StudentHeader
          {...{
            formik,
            locations,
            years,
            courseData,
            t,
            rowData,
            fileHeaders,
            fileName,
            setDialogOpen,
            selectedRows,
            setError,
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid container spacing={2} direction="row" display="flex" alignItems="center">
        <span className={classes.errorText}>{error}</span>
      </Grid>
      {showDetail()}

      <DialogAtom
        secHandle={() => setSwapCourseOrLocation(false)}
        isOpen={isSwapCourseDialog}
        dialogHeading={t('SWAP_SECTION')}
        customClass={classes.swapCourseDialog}
        footer={swapCourseDialogFooter}
        content={swapCourseLocation}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

The studentHeader component has the dropdown which I need to change and add a customize handleChange method. But since its only using formik.handleChange imma little bit confused.

2. Child Component -- StudentHeader

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { CSVLink } from 'react-csv';
import { Grid, Tooltip } from '@mui/material';
import FileDownloadOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FileDownloadOutlined';
import EmailOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmailOutlined';
import { FormikProvider } from 'formik';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setSelectedYear } from '../../../store/actions/getLocationCoordinator';
import { PerformantDropdown, PerfromantMultiValueDropdown } from '../../../components/atoms';
import styles from './style';
import MapPin from '../../../assets/images/map-pin.png';
import useStyles from '../../../custom-hooks/useStyles';
import { ColumnSelectIcon } from '../../../assets/svg';
import { NavigateRoutes } from '../../../constant';
import Constant from '../../../store/constant';
import { setLocalStorage } from '../../../utils/localStorageMethod';

function StudentHeader({
  formik,
  t,
  fileHeaders,
  years,
  locations,
  courseData,
  fileName,
  setDialogOpen,
  selectedRows,
  setError,
}) {
  const classes = useStyles(styles)();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  setLocalStorage('selectedLocation', '');
  setLocalStorage('selectedYear', '');
  // const locationCoordinatorData = useSelector((state) => state?.getLocationCoordinator);
  // const selectedYearRedux = locationCoordinatorData?.selectedYear;
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log(selectedYearRedux);
  // }, [selectedYearRedux]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage('locationDashboard', false);
    formik.setFieldValue('courseId', [courseData?.[0]?.id]);
  }, [courseData]);

  const sendBulkEmail = () => {
    if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
      setError('');
      const emailList = [];
      const emailParents = [];
      selectedRows?.forEach((row) => {
        emailList.push(row?.studentInfo?.manabadiEmail);
        emailParents.push(row?.parent1Info?.personalEmail?.toString());
        emailParents.push(row?.parent2Info?.personalEmail?.toString());
      });
      dispatch({ type: Constant.SET_MAIL_SUBJECT, payload: '' });
      dispatch({ type: Constant.SET_MAIL_BODY, payload: '' });
      dispatch({ type: Constant.RECIPIENTS, payload: emailList });
      dispatch({ type: Constant.MAIL_PARENTS, payload: emailParents });
      dispatch({ type: Constant.MAIL_FILTER, payload: 'Student' });
      setLocalStorage('selectedLocation', formik?.values?.locationId);
      setLocalStorage('selectedYear', formik?.values?.academicYear);
      setLocalStorage('showSelectAllinEmail', false);

      if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
        setLocalStorage('showLocationFilterRecipients', false);
        setLocalStorage('showLocationAnnouncementsRecipients', false);
      } else {
        setLocalStorage('showLocationFilterRecipients', false);
        setLocalStorage('showLocationAnnouncementsRecipients', false);
      }
      navigate(NavigateRoutes.LOCATION_COORDINATOR_EMAIL);
    } else {
      setError(t('SELECT_ATLEAST_ONE_STUDENT'));
    }
  };
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} direction="row" display="flex" alignItems="center">
      <FormikProvider value={formik}>
        <Grid item xs={4} sm={1.5} className={classes.year}>
          <PerformantDropdown
            minWidth="100%"
            label={t('YEAR')}
            labelId={t('YEAR')}
            id="academicYear"
            name="academicYear"
            value={formik.values.academicYear}
            handleChange={formik.handleChange}
            options={years}
            customClass="yearDropdown"
            variant="standard"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4.5} className={classes.locationDropdown}>
          <PerformantDropdown
            minWidth="100%"
            label={t('LOCATION')}
            id="locationId"
            name="locationId"
            value={formik.values.locationId}
            handleChange={formik.handleChange}
            options={locations}
            customClass="locationDropdown"
            variant="standard"
            icon={<img src={MapPin} alt="" className={classes.mapPinImg} />}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} className={classes.courseDropdown}>
          <PerfromantMultiValueDropdown
            minWidth="100%"
            label={t('COURSE')}
            value={formik.values.courseId}
            options={courseData}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            id="courseId"
            name="courseId"
            variant="standard"
            customClass="courseDropdown"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item md={1.4} />
        <Grid item xs={0.5} className={classes.gridActions}>
          {/* {selectedRows?.length ? ( */}
          <Tooltip title={t('DOWNLOAD')} placement="right">
            <div className={classes.header}>
              <CSVLink
                headers={fileHeaders}
                data={selectedRows}
                filename={`${fileName}.csv`}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <FileDownloadOutlinedIcon />

              </CSVLink>
            </div>
          </Tooltip>

          {/* ) : null} */}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={0.5} className={classes.gridActions} onClick={sendBulkEmail}>
          <Tooltip title={t('SEND_EMAIL')} placement="right">
            <div className={classes.header}>
              <EmailOutlinedIcon className={classes.header} />
            </div>
          </Tooltip>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          xs={0.5}
          onClick={() => setDialogOpen(true)}
          className={classes.gridActions}
        >
          {' '}
          <Tooltip title={t('UPDATE_SETTINGS')} placement="right">
            <div>
              <ColumnSelectIcon
                customClass={classes.columnSelectionIcon}
                strokeColor="#104F96"
              />
            </div>
          </Tooltip>
        </Grid>
      </FormikProvider>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default StudentHeader;
```

These two PerformatDropdown needs to be changed. I want to have a handleChange method which will change the value and dispatch a redux action which will store the changed value. The redux part I already solved, please tell me how can change the formik.handleChange??

Comment: You should be able to substitute a function that calls formic `handleChange` if you intend for it to keep working.  `handleChange={$event => {dispatchWhatever($event); formik.handleChange($event)}}`.  Be wary that if your redux store starts feeding back into the values of those components you can be in for a bad time.

Comment: Or we could do this

Answer (score 0):

or we could do this

```
  const handleYearChange = (e) => {
    formik.setFieldValue('academicYear', e.target.value);
    const payload = {
      id: e.target.value,
      name: e.target.value,
    };
    dispatch(setSelectedYear(payload));
  };
```

```
          <PerformantDropdown
            minWidth="100%"
            label={t('YEAR')}
            labelId={t('YEAR')}
            id="academicYear"
            name="academicYear"
            value={formik.values.academicYear}
            handleChange={(e) => handleYearChange(e)}
            options={years}
            customClass="yearDropdown"
            variant="standard"
          />
```

Comment: That's less extensible because you need to vary the field value